# Problem compiling a class passed as string because it has a dependancy

Tags: .net

I'm getting the following error  (in Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.GetMessage());) :

"The type or namespace name 'RequiredAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

However, if you check the code below, I have referenced (loaded?) RequiredAttribute which is in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.10\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll

```
        string classString = "public class ModelClass { public int Id { get; set; } [Required] public int ProjectId { get; set; } [Required] public string ModelName { get; set; } [Required] public string ClassCode { get; set; } public ModelClass() { ModelName = string.Empty; ClassCode = string.Empty; } }";

        // Parse and compile the source code
        var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(classString);  

        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation")
            .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
            .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
            .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(RequiredAttribute).Assembly.Location))
            .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(classString));
        
        var diagnostics = compilation.GetDiagnostics();
        if (diagnostics.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.GetMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: In `classString`, I suggest trying `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]` instead of just `[Required`] to see if that helps.

Comment: I can't. Input is passed by user. I have no control over it.
He passes a model and I generate the mockup.

Comment: I suggest you change it yourself, in code, with a hack if you have to, one time, just to see if it resolves the issue. That will isolate the problem and give you some idea how to move forward.

Comment: If it works, and it's simply namespace as an issue, see this answer: [Roslyn: Add using statements to syntax tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63695316/2791540)

Comment: it's now a differerent error but apparently related:The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to the assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
based on internet search, I think that I have added system.Runtime (I tried 2 launch below, the first and the last one

Comment: public static void AddNetFrameworkDefaultReferences()
        {
            AddAssembly("System.Runtime");         
            AddAssembly("System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll");
            References.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
            References.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Runtime.AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute).Assembly.Location));
        }

Comment: @john Wu: The point is that it must be generic. In a form, a user will enter a c# model and I will generate the mockup. I must be able to load into memory the class ( provided as input string) with all dependancies and generate the mockup. I believe that I will also need all field annotations dependancies (json, etc...).

Comment: The problem is that the code is using a symbol (`Required`) that is ambiguous without additional code. Perhaps you could just prepend `using Required = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute;`
 to the text before you parse it.

Answer (score 0):

1. John Wu was right. It tested the compilation by passing just the class (public class etc...). I needed to pass the full file with the using definitions and namespace.
2. I'm loading the necessary dll for dotnet 6

   ```
    public static bool AddAssembly(string assemblyDll)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyDll)) return false;

        var file = Path.GetFullPath(assemblyDll);

        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            // check framework or dedicated runtime app folder
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            file = Path.Combine(path, assemblyDll);
            if (!File.Exists(file))
                return false;
        }

        if (References.Any(r => r.FilePath == file)) return true;

        try
        {
            var reference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(file);
            References.Add(reference);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static void AddNetFrameworkDefaultReferences()
    {
        AddAssembly("mscorlib.dll");
        AddAssembly("System.dll");
        AddAssembly("System.Core.dll");
        AddAssembly("System.Runtime.dll");
        AddAssembly("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
        AddAssembly("System.Net.Http.dll");
        AddAssembly("System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll");
        References.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(JsonSerializer).Assembly.Location));
        References.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
    }
   ```